# Apple TV – How to only change focus when "Menu" button is tapped

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, focus-engine

I'm working on a simple board game. I have buttons in the left column like "New Game", "Settings" etc.(let's call it "Menu View"). The rest of the screen is the "Board View" with the current state of the game.

Is it possible to handle when user taps the "Menu" button on the Apple TV Remote control just to navigate from the "Board View" to my "Menu View" instead of closing my app? I have both "Menu View" and "Board View" in the same controller, maybe I need to adjust the controller hierarchy?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually, I noticed overriding `pressesEnded` won't cancel the Menu button press for the first time after launching the app. Using `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the other hand does:

```
    let menuTapGestureRegocnizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "menuTapped")
    menuTapGestureRegocnizer.allowedPressTypes = [UIPressType.Menu.rawValue]
    view.addGestureRecognizer(menuTapGestureRegocnizer)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the pressesEnded method and trigger the navigation segues manually

```
override func pressesEnded(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    for press in presses {
        if(press.type == UIPressType.Menu) {
           // Do what you want
           // ...
        } else {
            super.pressesEnded(presses, withEvent: event)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This looks good, I can actually handle the Menu button tap. The problem is that I still can't cancel the menu action of closing the app. Any idea?
EDIT: On real device, it looks it works! Thanks!

Comment: Be careful. My App was rejected: 'The menu button on the Siri Remote does not behave as expected in your app. '

Comment: I actually noticed, it doesn't work 100%. When I launch the app and I start the game (get focus in the controller on right) and tap the Menu button for the first time, I the focus moves to the menu (controller on left) but the app closes anyway. After starting the app again (waking it up form background) the menu button work the right way (closes the app only if I'm in the Menu controller).